# lme4: prevent 'glmer' to have zero estimated random coefficient

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, poisson-distribution, random-effects-model

I use the `glmer` function with the Poisson family from `lme4`.
My simulated data are constituted of 3600 individuals, and a variable **A** with 30 levels and a second variable **B** with 2 levels.
I have simulated random effects for the 2 variables from Normal distribution whose standards deviation are equal to  0.5 (far from zero!).

In the model, the random effets are of the form:
`(0 + B | A ) + (1| A )`

(The complete model is of the form:
`event ~ -1 + cov1 : factor(B) + cov2 + offset(log(time))+ (0 + B | A ) + (1| A )`
. `cov1` is categorical variable. `cov2` is a binary covariate. Both are fixed effects)

Despite this, the model estimates the second random coefficient at zero in 70% of the simulations, which for me is a failure.

Does anyone have any advice to prevent the model from estimating the random coefficients at zero, maybe by changing the parameters of the Control?
I don't want to simplify the model, I need it to be in the above formulation.
I tried the two optimizers (Nelder-Mead and bobyqa); there was no change in the proportion of failures.

Thanks a lot for any help,

Comment: I think you will need to provide more details, ideally your simulation code.

Comment: @RobertLong I can provide it with pleasure but it is very long...

Comment: Perhaps you can simplify it to demonstrate the problem ?

Comment: @RobertLong Everything is now available

Comment: Why aren't the individuals represented in the random effects structure? Reading the question. A and B sound like fixed effects.

Comment: At first, I didn't show the complete model. I have edited my post to show the complete models. I have two fixed effects, here named `cov1` and `cov2`. Both are categorical variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found very useful advices in the Ben Bolker document:
https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#singular-models-random-effect-variances-estimated-as-zero-or-correlations-estimated-as---1

In particular, the advice to use the "blme" package was a great help to me.
This solved all my problems with the random coefficient estimated at zero.
Note that this package is very easy to use when you are used to `lme4`.